# pinv() function NaN matrix

Tags: matlab, image-processing, nan

I'm trying to recover reflectance and illumination from an input image.
The problem is in the %%%find r section ( reflectance).
The result of the 'pinv' is a NaN matrix... why ?
Code:

```
c = imread('cats.jpg');
c = im2double(c(:, :, 1));

im = log(c);

 filters = {fspecial('laplacian', 0.1) fspecial('laplacian', 0.3,fspecial('laplacian',   0.5) fspecial('laplacian', 0.7) fspecial('laplacian', 0.9)};


 %%% conv

 o = cell(1, 5);

 for i = 1:5
    o{i} = conv2(im, filters{i}, 'same');
 end

 %%% median

 imd = o{1};
for i = 2:5
    imd = cat(3, imd, o{i});
end

r_n = median(imd, 3);

%%% find r

[X,Y]=size(r_n);
fftr=zeros(X,Y);
fft_filters = cell(1, 5);
for i = 1:5
    requiredpaddingX = X-3;
     requiredpaddingY=Y-3;
     filters{i}=padarray(filters{i},[requiredpaddingY requiredpaddingX],'post');


     fft_filters{i} = fft2(filters{i});
     fft_filterspinv{i}=pinv(fft_filters{i});   %%% HERE 
     fftr=r+r_n .* fft_filterspinv{i};
 end
```

Comment: What does fft_filters{i} look like?

Comment: It's a 5 cell 'vector', every cell contains a matrix ( the laplacian filter after FFT).
Example : fft_filters{1} is an NXM matrix...

Comment: So fft_filters{i} is a matrix, correct? If you printed it out, does it look 'normal'?

Comment: yes, a matrix after Fourier transform. 
I just used the Convolution theorem so I can make pseudo inverse with multiplication ( I don't know how to do pseudo inverse with convolutions)

Answer (score 0):

Pinv doesn't work with sparse functions and laplacian is sparse